# Swift dates are equivalent under 30 nanoseconds

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, nsdate

I noticed that when comparing two instances of a Swift `Date` with `==`, they qualify as the same date when the difference in `DateComponents.nanoseconds` is less than 30. For example:

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let startComps = DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
let endComps = DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 29)

let startDate = calendar.date(from: startComps)!
let endDate = calendar.date(from: endComps)!
print(startDate == endDate)
//prints true, changing 29 to 30 prints false
```

The behavior is the same if comparing with `startDate.compare(endDate) == .orderedSame`. I couldn't find any mention of this in the docs or headers. Is there a logical reason for 30 nanoseconds to be the cutoff for equality?

Comment: Cocoa dates are documented to be precise only to milliseconds.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm not particularly concerned about nanosecond precision, just curious as to the reason why 29/30 is the consistent cutoff point. Perhaps this is too low-level to be documented.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, where is that documented?

Comment: The date is stored as a `TimeInverval` aka `Double` and therefore has limited precision. You'll notice that `startDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` and `endDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` are identical.

Comment: The [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-BCIDBADB), @KenThomases, although I guess it's expressed more as a feature than a limitation: "...giving precision within milliseconds for dates 10,000 years apart." I probably mentally translated it. Also, it's actually about `NSTimeInterval`, so my original comment is too strong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dates are represented internally as a `Double`. `Double`s have a limited precision. Your first date there has an internal value of `504950400.000000000000000` (when printed at 15 decimal places). The next higher representable value is `504950400.000000059604645`. It just so happens that your end date, if you set the nanoseconds to `30`, is `504950400.000000059604645` (which actually corresponds to a nanoseconds value of `59`).

Which is to say, in January of 2017, `Date` can only distinguish between 59-nanosecond intervals. Meanwhile back in January of 2001, `Date` can distinguish every single nanosecond. And in 2027 it will distinguish between 119-nanosecond intervals.

Comment: (If someone want to verify the above numbers: They correspond to the GMT+0 timezone.)

Comment: How do people know all this :O